# react pomodoro like timer with setInterval

Tags: reactjs, timer, setinterval

The Idea is - I press 'start timer' and a function sets the variable  'sessionSeconds' based on whether its work 25mins or rest 5mins session (true/false). Problem is , when interval restarts,  function doesn't update this 'currentSessionSeconds'.  Maybe it's something with lifecycles or I should use useEffect somehow..

```
const TimeTracker = () => {
  const [work, setWork] = useState(25);
  const [rest, setRest] = useState(5);
  const [remainingTime,setRemainingTime]= useState(25);
  const [iswork, setIswork] = useState(true);

  function startTimer() {
    clearInterval(interval);
    let sessionSeconds = iswork? work * 60 : rest * 60
   
    interval = setInterval(() => {
      sessionSeconds--
      if (duration <= 0) {
       setIswork((iswork) => !iswork)
       updateTime(sessionSeconds)
       startTimer();
      }
    }, 1000);

  function updateTime(seconds){
    setRemainingTime(seconds)
  }
 }
return (

  <div>
    <p>
      {remainingTime}
    </p>
    <button onClick={startTimer}>timer</button>
  </div>

 );
 }
```

I didnt include other code for converting, etc to not over clutter.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get your code working to test it since it is missing a }.

I changed your code to include use effect and everything seems to work fine.

https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-saha-0dxde?file=/src/App.js

```
const TimeTracker = () => {
    /*  In your code you used use state however you didn't change 
        the state of these variables so I set them to constants.
        You can also pass them through props.
    */
    const work = 25;
    const rest = 5;
    const [remainingTime, setRemainingTime] = useState(work * 60);
    const [isWork, setIsWork] = useState(true);
    const [isTimerActive, setIsTimerActive] = useState(false);

    const startTimerHandler = () => {
        isWork ? setRemainingTime(work * 60) : setRemainingTime(rest * 60);
        setIsTimerActive(true);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!isTimerActive) return;
        if (remainingTime === 0) {
            setIsWork((prevState) => !prevState);
            setIsTimerActive(false);
        }
        const timeOut = setTimeout(() => {
            setRemainingTime((prevState) => prevState - 1);
        }, 1000);

        /* The return function will be called before each useEffect 
            after the first one and will clear previous timeout
        */
        return () => {
            clearTimeout(timeOut);
        };
    }, [remainingTime, isTimerActive]);

    return (
        <div>
            <p>{remainingTime}</p>
            <button onClick={startTimerHandler}>timer</button>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I also need this app to automatically restart with "rest" session, and after that "work", etc.     I tried adding startTimerHandler()  in useEffect aftert seconds hit zero.  And it works quite well, but it first time when i run,  work session loops two times before switching to rest.  After that it's ok.  Maybe you know how to solve this? https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-kowalevski-ief45?file=/src/App.js:864-884

Comment: That's because the state hasn't been updated yet when you can startTimerHandler. Their are multiple ways to handle this but I think the best one is to use a reducer to handle the multiple state change at once. 
Sadly I don't have time right now to help you implement it :/ https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer

Comment: thanks, you helped enough.   By the way, maybe in the class component, this would work easier/differently?